# Digital Inverter or Analogue Inverter?

Tags: inverter

Can any one recommend / compare performance of digital inverter and analogue inverter for home UPS application? Which one is better, Analaogue or digital ? and why?

Comment: Do you mean `pure-sine` vs `modifed-sine` inverters?

Answer (score 10):

I think you have been confused by the [overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) of the term "inverter".

A UPS ([uninterruptable power supply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply)) converts a low d.c. battery voltage to an approximation of a sinusoidal mains (high) voltage. Since it is the opposite of the common power supply design which converts high voltage mains to low voltage d.c., it can be called an inverter. But it has nothing to do with analogue and digital inverters.

A digital inverter is also called a [NOT gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverter_%28logic_gate%29) and simply outputs the boolean opposite of the input. Voltage levels are defined by the logic family and supply rails.

An [analogue inverter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Inverting_amplifier) is an amplifier which produces opposite phase signals to the input, so as the input goes up, the output goes down.

Answer (score 0):

*I think the terms used here are what is causing the problem understanding. First what most people call a inverter is package consisting of a rectifier (fixed or controlled) which produces a dc voltage from a ac voltage. the dc is then supplied to the inverter section thru a bus. the inverter then produces a series of square waves some positive going some negative going. when the average of the square waves is taken you get a near sinusoidal wave form, but it is not a true ac it is digital. Therefore it is a digital inverter. A ac inverter is just as the name implies it is a device which produces a true sinusoidal ac sine wave as it output. In both cases the frequency and the amplitude of the output wave can be varied.*